# Create nested div containers inside each other and change their colors

Tags: html, css

I'm extremely new to coding with html and css. I wanted to do this exercise where I basically create a bunch of boxes inside of each other, and change their colors randomly using a button. I'm struggling quite a bit to align these three boxes inside each other uniformly. A requirement of this is to use absolute positioning in my solution.

My end goal is to align 10 of them inside one another, leading to my next goal.
Is it possible to change each of their colors randomly? I'm thinking of creating a random color generator, and applying their output individually to each div element.

https://jsfiddle.net/3epp2t0t/

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>BOXES</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="first">
      <div id="second"></div>
      <div id="third"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
#first {
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      background: red;
      position: absolute;
    }

    #first #second {
      position: absolute;
      width: 80%;
      height: 80%;
      background: green;
      margin: 10px;
    }

    #first #third {
      position: absolute;
      width: 60%;
      height: 60%;
      background: blue;
      margin: 20px;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, you can. But you will need to learn javascript to do this. Since actually your code and the jsfiddle dont have javascript, I think you didnt have knowledge about it. I recommend you to take a course of javascript, at codecademy.com they have interactive courses and the free ones are pretty good. Once you have a little knowledge about js feel free to ask for support here.

Comment: You can solve this with javascript. See this answer and you will have your color changing divs in no time! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799125/random-color-on-different-divs

Answer (score 0):

Here you go hope this helps you with your project. Using only HTML and CSS no JS needed.
https://codepen.io/mary-ann-dul/pen/XqNGXO

HTML:

```
<div class="center">
  <div class="first">  
  </div>
    <div class="second">
  </div>
  <div class="third">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
     background-color: #fff;

}
@keyframes  random {
    15% { background-color: red; } 
    30% { background-color: yellow; } 
    45% { background-color: green; } 
    60% { background-color: blue; }
    75% { background-color: white; }  
}


.first
{
 background-color: #fff;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
   margin:auto;
  position:absolute;
  top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:10;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation: random 3s infinite;
     animation: random 3s infinite;
}

.second
{
 background-color: #fff;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
   margin:auto;
 position:absolute;
  top:50; bottom:60;   left:50; right:50;
  transition: all 0.9s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation: random 10s infinite;
     animation: random 10s infinite;
}
.third
{ 
  background-color: #fff;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
   margin:auto;
 position:absolute;
  top:75; bottom:75;   left:75; right:75;
  transition: all 0.9s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation: random 15s infinite;
     animation: random 15s infinite;

}
```