# Js random movement foreach element using switch

Tags: javascript

The problem I tried to using switch for random movement it works! but all the elements moving the same movement, not random, so I want each of them moves random

The output: https://duck-hunt.ahmedbr123.repl.co/

## REMEMBER

#### I want to solve the problem by using switch

The code:

```
 for (var n = 0; n < boxr.length; ++n)  {
 let lol =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1
  let dml1 = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(boxr[n]).getPropertyValue("left"));
  let dmt1 = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(boxr[n]).getPropertyValue("top"));
    // I sit by myself coding to the moon trying get to you
switch (lol) {
  case 1:
    boxr[n].style.transform = 'translate(-50%,-50%)'
    boxr[n].style.animation = 'animate 500ms steps(3) infinite'
    boxr[n].style.left = dml1 + 2 + 'px'
    break;
  case 2:
    boxr[n].style.transform = 'translate(-50%,-50%) scaleX(-1)'
    boxr[n].style.animation = 'animater 500ms steps(3) infinite'
    boxr[n].style.left = dml1 - sms + 'px'
    break;
  case 3:
     boxr[n].style.transform = 'translate(-50%,-50%)'
     boxr[n].style.animation = 'animatel 500ms steps(3) infinite'
     boxr[n].style.top = dmt1 - sms + 'px'
    break;
  case 4:
    if(boxr[n].style.animation = 'animatel 500ms steps(3) infinite' || boxr[n].style.animation == 'animate 500ms steps(3) infinite') {
    boxr[n].style.animation = 'animate 500ms steps(3) infinite'
    } else if(boxr[n].style.transform = 'translate(-50%,-50%) scaleX(-1)' && boxr[n].style.animation == 'animateS 500ms steps(3) infinite') {
      boxr[n].style.transform = 'translate(-50%,-50%) scaleX(-1)'
      boxr[n].style.animation = 'animate 500ms steps(3) infinite'
    }
    boxr[n].style.top = dmt1 + sms + 'px'
    break;
  case 5:
    boxr[n].style.transform = 'translate(-50%,-50%)'
    boxr[n].style.animation = 'animateS 500ms steps(3) infinite'
    boxr[n].style.left = dml1 + sms + 'px'
    boxr[n].style.top = dmt1 - sms + 'px'
    break;
  case 6:
    boxr[n].style.transform = 'translate(-50%,-50%) scaleX(-1)'
    boxr[n].style.animation = 'animateS 500ms steps(3) infinite'
    boxr[n].style.top = dmt1 - sms + 'px'
    boxr[n].style.left = dml1 - sms + 'px'
    break;
  case 7:
    boxr[n].style.transform = 'translate(-50%,-50%)'
    boxr[n].style.animation = 'animate 500ms steps(3) infinite'
    boxr[n].style.left = dml1 + sms + 'px'
    boxr[n].style.top = dmt1 + sms + 'px'
    break;
  case 8:
    boxr[n].style.transform = 'translate(-50%,-50%) scaleX(-1)'
    boxr[n].style.animation = 'animate 500ms steps(3) infinite'
    boxr[n].style.left = dml1 - sms + 'px'
    boxr[n].style.top = dmt1 + sms + 'px'
    break;
}
```

### Edit:

#### My problem is similar to this [Random color on different div's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799125/random-color-on-different-divs/27799274)

Comment: You need to set `lol` to a new value each time through the loop.

Comment: No I meant when a case run it makes all the elements with the same class run the same movement not different than each other

Comment: I understand that. It's because you never change `lol`  during the loop. So every iteration executes the same case.

Comment: Check the link again

Comment: I knew what did you meant but not what I looking for

Comment: I didn't check the link at all. All important information should be in the question, not at a remote link.

Comment: My problem is kinda similar to this <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799125/random-color-on-different-divs/27799274>

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `lol` to a random number each time through the loop, so that each element gets different random movements.

```js
for (var n = 0; n < boxr.length; ++n) {
  let dml1 = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(boxr[n]).getPropertyValue("left"));
  let dmt1 = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(boxr[n]).getPropertyValue("top"));
  let lol = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1
  switch (lol) {
    case 1:
      boxr[n].style.transform = 'translate(-50%,-50%)'
      boxr[n].style.animation = 'animate 500ms steps(3) infinite'
      boxr[n].style.left = dml1 + 2 + 'px'
      break;
    case 2:
      boxr[n].style.transform = 'translate(-50%,-50%) scaleX(-1)'
      boxr[n].style.animation = 'animater 500ms steps(3) infinite'
      boxr[n].style.left = dml1 - sms + 'px'
      break;
    case 3:
      boxr[n].style.transform = 'translate(-50%,-50%)'
      boxr[n].style.animation = 'animatel 500ms steps(3) infinite'
      boxr[n].style.top = dmt1 - sms + 'px'
      break;
    case 4:
      if (boxr[n].style.animation = 'animatel 500ms steps(3) infinite' || boxr[n].style.animation == 'animate 500ms steps(3) infinite') {
        boxr[n].style.animation = 'animate 500ms steps(3) infinite'
      } else if (boxr[n].style.transform = 'translate(-50%,-50%) scaleX(-1)' && boxr[n].style.animation == 'animateS 500ms steps(3) infinite') {
        boxr[n].style.transform = 'translate(-50%,-50%) scaleX(-1)'
        boxr[n].style.animation = 'animate 500ms steps(3) infinite'
      }
      boxr[n].style.top = dmt1 + sms + 'px'
      break;
    case 5:
      boxr[n].style.transform = 'translate(-50%,-50%)'
      boxr[n].style.animation = 'animateS 500ms steps(3) infinite'
      boxr[n].style.left = dml1 + sms + 'px'
      boxr[n].style.top = dmt1 - sms + 'px'
      break;
    case 6:
      boxr[n].style.transform = 'translate(-50%,-50%) scaleX(-1)'
      boxr[n].style.animation = 'animateS 500ms steps(3) infinite'
      boxr[n].style.top = dmt1 - sms + 'px'
      boxr[n].style.left = dml1 - sms + 'px'
      break;
    case 7:
      boxr[n].style.transform = 'translate(-50%,-50%)'
      boxr[n].style.animation = 'animate 500ms steps(3) infinite'
      boxr[n].style.left = dml1 + sms + 'px'
      boxr[n].style.top = dmt1 + sms + 'px'
      break;
    case 8:
      boxr[n].style.transform = 'translate(-50%,-50%) scaleX(-1)'
      boxr[n].style.animation = 'animate 500ms steps(3) infinite'
      boxr[n].style.left = dml1 - sms + 'px'
      boxr[n].style.top = dmt1 + sms + 'px'
      break;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but the main problem is not that

Comment: The problem is that, it's giving me the same movement in every element.

Comment: It shouldn't, since each element gets a different case.

Comment: No, it doesnt the case work on each element

Comment: But `lol` is different each time because of `let lol = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1` so each element gets a different case.